# Facebook SDK not working swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, swift3, cocoapods

Apparently swift 3 support has been added to the Facebook SDK, but when I try to add it using pods I get the error "Convert to current Swift syntax", any help would be appreciated.

This is the error I get after opening the workspace after running "pod install":

[image: The xcode error after opening the xcode work space]

This is what is in my pod file:

[image]

Comment: It just suggests you to convert it to the current syntax. Where is the problem?

Comment: This suggests that it isn't swift 3?, and after conversion it is full of errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook said they would release swift 3.0 support when swift reaches GM, so if it is available, this would be the way to go. Otherwise their Github page do have Swift 3.0...though in beta. [Facebook Swift 3.0 Github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-swift)

First update your local specs repo by doing this:

```
Pod repo update
```

Then in your pod file do:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'Project' do
dynamic frameworks
use_frameworks!

# Pods for Project
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
pod 'FacebookShare'


post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
    end
  end
end
end
```

Then install the pod

```
Pod install
```

Edit:

**post_install**

> This hook allows you to make any last changes to the generated Xcode project before it is written to disk, or any other tasks you might want to perform.

Customising the build settings of all targets

```
post_install do |installer|
installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
target.build_configurations.each do |config|
  config.build_settings['GCC_ENABLE_OBJC_GC'] = 'supported'
    end
  end
end
```

> The Installer is responsible of taking a Podfile and transform it in the Pods libraries. It also integrates the user project so the Pods libraries can be used out of the box.
>
> The Installer is capable of doing incremental updates to an existing Pod installation.

More information about the available options is found [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoapods/Pod/Installer/) and [here](https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#xcodeproj)

Comment: this worked great, could you just elaborate more on what the last 5 lines of the pod file are doing?

Answer (score -1):

First this is not error, it's a dialog box that, like i already said in the comment, suggests you to "Convert to current Swift syntax", because there are some methods, etc, that are deprecated.

You have 2 options, the first is to convert it and if there are errors (it's normal) you can try to fix them, and the second one is to integrate it manually, and if yo don't know how to do it you can follow some tutorial, [like this one](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/facebook-integration-using-swift).